Time and Date Data Incorrectly Plotted
my issue is that the link (displayed in the tooltip for trouble shooting) ends up in the wrong bar and the rest of the tooltip is fine.  March has April's link. The links won't work in the sample but the month is in the start and end of the dates...
my chart

Can you elaborate? The issue is not clear

yes there are links in the tooltip that represent links used in the app to access detailed data.    normally they are not in the tooltip.  Each start and end search has a month and a %  that represents the month the link is for and it should match the date in the data.  I have verified this.  All the data in the tooltip is in the right place on the bar but the links are on the wrong bar.  jan has feb, mar has april has mys links,

Sorry but it is difficult to see. Can you give one example datapoint that is incorrect and where it should be instead? Which exact fields are wrong?

sure if you hover over march the blue bar the dates are march and the link starts with 04& for search_start and end witch is April.  In the app it takes you to the wrong month.....

I'm not observing that. I see links start with 03 for march blue bar. This might be a UTC issue but hard to say for sure.

I'll show you with an answer.

Example of what I can see in your tooltip.


changed time unit to utc spot on
